# Most efficient way to count sub-dataframe rows for each row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, optimization

Imagine that I have some pandas dataframe, which looks like this:

```
                    creationDate
188080 2019-08-01 21:28:39+03:00
188081 2019-08-01 21:33:13+03:00
188082 2019-08-01 21:39:53+03:00
188083 2019-08-01 21:43:24+03:00
188084 2019-08-01 21:48:17+03:00
188085 2019-08-01 21:52:56+03:00
188086 2019-08-01 21:58:27+03:00
188087 2019-08-01 22:10:50+03:00
188088 2019-08-01 22:14:58+03:00
188089 2019-08-01 22:17:43+03:00
```

I want to create a new column, named `density`. For each row it means "How many rows there are after current cell `creationDate` and before current cell `creationDate` + `1 hour`"

I have a vectorized function, but on my dataset (about 1.500.000 rows) it doesn't work very fast (took about 5 minutes on my laptop).

```py
def get_density(date, distance_in_minute):
    start_datetime = date
    end_datetime = date + np.timedelta64(distance_in_minute, 'm')

    return df.loc[
        (df['creationDate'] >= str(start_datetime)) & (df['creationDate'] < str(end_datetime))
    ].shape[0]

np_get_density = np.vectorize(lambda x: get_density(x, 60))

df['density'] = np_get_density(df['creationDate'])
```

How can I optimize this query? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a good candidate for using the `map` method of a `multiprocessing.Pool`. The `get_density` function would essentially be the worker function.

However, a worker function only gets one argument, and it would be good to also supply it with a reference to the dataframe. So use `functools.partial` to supply `distance_in_minute` and the dataframe to `get_density` before using the result as the worker function.

In the best case, if your CPU has *N* cores this will make it approximately *N* times faster. So if you have a 4-core CPU, time should go from 5 minutes to approximately 1.25 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

How about using **Dask** . It is a library for parallel computing in python and can be much faster than pure python.

Some notes (nice to haves) -

1) It doesn't support multindexing.

2) Proper DataTypes should be assigned to the columns.

```py
from dask import dataframe as dd
from multiprocessing import cpu_count
import pandas as pd

df=df.reset_index()
df.creationDate=pd.DataFrame(df.creationDate)

def get_density(date):
    distance_in_minute=60
    start_datetime = date
    end_datetime = pd.to_datetime(date) + np.timedelta64(distance_in_minute, 'm')

    return (df.loc[
        (df['creationDate'] >= str(start_datetime)) & (df['creationDate'] < str(end_datetime))
    ].shape[0])

nCores = cpu_count()

dd=dd.from_pandas(df,npartitions=nCores)
dd['density']=dd.creationDate.apply(get_density,meta=('density', int))
df=dd.compute()
```

Also better solution than `np.vectorize()` can be `df.apply`.
You can try the following:

```
df['density']=(df.apply(lambda x: get_density(x.creationDate),axis=1))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html) with a time once you have created a series with a `datetimeIndex`. Because you want to look forward in time, you need to reverse the order of your index first by adding the time delta between each date and the max to a random date, once you have reverse the order of the column creationDate with `[::-1]`. Here is one way:

```
df['density'] = (pd.Series(1, #create a Series with 1 as value but you can use anything
                                  # index need a start date, anyone is fine
                           index= pd.to_datetime("today") + 
                                  # time delta between each rows once reverse and the max
                               (df.creationDate.max() - df.creationDate[::-1]))
                   .rolling('20T') # with the given data, I use 20 minutes as interval,
                                   # change it to 1H for 1 hour, or 60T
                   .count() #count the number of rows within the rolling window
                   .values[::-1]) #reverse the values to come back to the original order
```

and you get

```
print (df)
                    creationDate  density
188080 2019-08-01 21:28:39+03:00      5.0
188081 2019-08-01 21:33:13+03:00      5.0
188082 2019-08-01 21:39:53+03:00      5.0
188083 2019-08-01 21:43:24+03:00      4.0
188084 2019-08-01 21:48:17+03:00      3.0
188085 2019-08-01 21:52:56+03:00      3.0 #here you have 3 rows within 20 minutes
188086 2019-08-01 21:58:27+03:00      4.0
188087 2019-08-01 22:10:50+03:00      3.0
188088 2019-08-01 22:14:58+03:00      2.0
188089 2019-08-01 22:17:43+03:00      1.0
```